# how can I use ansible to push playbooks with SSH keys authentification

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys, ansible-inventory

I am new to ansible and try to push playbooks to my nodes. I would like to push via ssh-keys. Here is my playbook:

```
- name: nginx install and start services
 hosts: <ip>
 vars:
   ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "/path/to/.ssh/id_ed25519"
 become: true

 tasks:
 - name: install nginx
   yum:
     name: nginx
     state: latest
 
 - name: start service nginx
   service:
     name: nginx
     state: started
```

Here is my inventory:

```
<ip> ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

before I push, I check if it works: `ansible-playbook -i /home/myuser/.ansible/hosts nginx.yaml --check`

it gives me:
`fatal: [ip]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: user@ip: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}`

On that server I don't have root privileges, I cant do sudo. That's why I use my own inventory in my home directory. To the target node where I want to push that nginx playbook, I can do a SSH connection and perform a login. The public key is on the remote server in /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25119.pub

What am i missing?

Comment: The public key content has to be in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the connection user on the remote server.

Comment: if you don't have root privileges, how would you be able to install nginx or any other package ?

Answer (score 0):

Copy /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg into the directory from which you are running the `nginx.yaml` playbook, or somewhere else per the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings-locations

Then edit that file to change this line:

```
#private_key_file = /path/to/file
```

to read:

```
private_key_file = /path/to/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Also check the remote `user_user` entry.